# How to delete menu item defined in a parent major from within derived mode?

Tags: menu-bar, derived-mode

I'm creating custom major mode derived from `js-mode` which comes with it's own menu entry "Javascript" (top-level entry, between Tools & Help (sorry, not sure what the correct name for that UI element is)).

I would like to hide/remove that menu since I don't have need for it (deriving from `js-mode` mostly for indentation settings which I know is probably an overkill).

I found this piece of information [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Deleting-menus-and-menu-options.html):

```
(define-key global-map [menu-bar words] nil)
```

so I have tried calling

```
(define-key global-map [menu-bar javascript] nil)
```

from inside `define-derived-mode` and `my-mode-hook`, but neither option worked (`javascript` menu bar name was guessed based on the UI label as I am not sure where can I check the actual name).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong with this approach? Or perhaps there is another way to hide/remove menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your major mode is defined with something like:

```
(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    <my-own-bindings>
    map))

(define-derived-mode my-mode js-mode "My"
  "Major mode for My language."
  <my-own-settings>)
```

then you can try to put

```
(define-key map [menu-bar JavaScript] #'undefined)
```

somewhere within the `<my-own-bindings>`.

Comment: `defvar my-mode-map...` code didn't work "out of the box" but it pointed me in the right direction - checking how to create own key map. Also had to add `(use-local-map my-mode-map)` within `<my-own-settings>` to actually activate new key map.

Comment: `define-derived-mode` already does the `use-local-map` for you, so you probably have a bug elsewhere [ BTW, the `defvar` above had a missing paren at the end of the line that starts with `(let`, which probably explains your problem with it ].